# How to access SQLite table programmatically (convert string to table name)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple sqlite database with several tables like this

schedule_20140824
schedule_20140825
schedule_20140826
...

How do I generate a select statement into a table for given a date?

For example, let's say today is the 26th and I wanted my app to access today's schedule table. What is the correct way to do the following?

```
    SELECT * FROM 'schedule_'||strftime('%Y%m%d','now');
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite itself cannot generate SQL dynamically.

You have to do this in your programming language:

```py
db.execute("SELECT * FROM schedule_" + date)
```

Comment: What about storing table names in a table? Is there any way to access the names as a target for SELECT FROM? Thanks!

Comment: That makes no difference.